# Animate initial vector drawing in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, vector

I see several content, where an icon has an animated drawing, so it looks like the icon is drawing actually. For example the site http://www.baeldung.com/ use it for all his drawing (in menu bar at top). Another example is the fingerprint icon on the android lock screen. If the screen is activated, the fingerprint is "actually drawing".

How could I implement something like this in C# and WPF? It will be a pain to write the whole animation for every icon (there are up to 200 in our library).

Edit: the icons are vector images with a path value, for example from https://materialdesignicons.com/ or different sites.

Comment: And what is the format of your icons?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say that the icons are vector data with a path value (for example from https://materialdesignicons.com/ or different sites)